# Java serialization rename field

Tags: java, serialization

Is there any way to serialize some fields with different name? For example I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializeable {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
}
```

And I want it to be serialized, but also want the field `name` be renamed to `a1` and field `lastName` be renamed to `a2`.

Actually my app provides a hessian web service. As far as I know hessian uses java serialization for serializing objects and stream them to client.

Comment: You could try and implement your own `private synchronized void writeObject( java.io.ObjectOutputStream s )  throws IOException`

Comment: Could you give me an example in aswers?

Comment: Explained in question.

Comment: Let's say that one part of the organization produces these serializations and the other part consumes them. The part that produces them, and the associated .java files, gets to define what both the .java files and the serialized data look like. Period. The other part of the organization doesn't have any choice but to follow suit, in both respects. This is not a programming problem at all, it is a management problem,

Comment: AFAIK default serialization depends more on order and data types than on names thus _if only the name changes_ it should be fine.  _But_ if you expect such a misunderstanding between departments and no organizational counter measures then I'd expect more differences than just names.In that case I'd suggest using something else than binary serialization e.g. JSON, key=value pairs etc. That way order  and types would become less important and names could be mapped. Besides that you might even need an adapter in between to handle differences in semantics.

Comment: @Thomas Changing the name changes the recovery from the serialized stream. The value for the old name will not be recovered as the value for the new name.

Comment: @EJP I see, thanks for pointing that out (I don't use standard serialization that often). In that case one could implement a custom serialization that doesn't depend on names but that would still not be the best solution for the actual problem. :)

Comment: @EJP That's why I said focusing on the reason of this matter will be distracting.

Comment: @A.v yet sometimes focusing on the reasons for some requirement might lead to more basic problems and solving those might turn the current problem into an academic question.

Comment: @Thomas I agree.
I guess because of bureaucracy we have to change our understanding and think like our ws main client.

Comment: The 'reason of this matter' is irrelevant. The fact is that whoever produces the data and the code that caused it has already dictated the matter in its entirety. It appears that you have another part of the organization that wants to use different Java classes for the same data. The simple fact of the matter is that, without using extraordinary measures, they can't, and that the question should never have arisen in the first place. This is a management problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a management problem, not a programing problem.

Comment: The cause of the problem may be management problem but the problem is still on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend to use some sort of data format like *XML* or *JSON*, which will make your task much easier since you can write your custom "(de-)serializers" to perform the transformation for you.

If you need to work with Javas object serialization, you need both classes to have the same class name (package name and class name) and additionally have a **serialVersionUID** attached to it with the same value in order for the class serialization to read the class back.

```
package testbench;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public MyClass(final String name, final String lastName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    private void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(name);
        out.writeUTF(lastName);
    }

    private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        name = in.readUTF();
        lastName = in.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + lastName;
    }

}
```

The client can use a different class with other methods and fields:

```
package testbench;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String a1;
    private String a2;

    public MyClass(final String a1, final String a2) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    private void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(a1);
        out.writeUTF(a2);
    }

    private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        a1 = in.readUTF();
        a2 = in.readUTF();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return a1 + " " + a2;
    }

}
```